# Windows Phone 8 app crashes when changing between pages

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am working on Windows Phone app development. In my app there is a button on page 1 which takes you to page 2, and there is another button on page 2 which takes you to page 3, and when I press back key it takes me to page 2 but when I try to go again to page 3 by clicking the button, my app crashes.

> P1 -> P2 -> P3

But when I press the back button, it navigates me to P2

> P3 -> P2

Now when I again try to go to P3 my app crashes:

> P2 -> P3 (app crashed)

Code on page 2:

```
private void show_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (to.Text == "" &&   from.Text =="" )
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter  station", "ATTENTION!!", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
    }
    else if (station.Contains(from.Text) && station.Contains(to.Text))
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/result.xaml?source=" + from.Text + "&destination=" +      to.Text, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
    else
    {
        var rlt = MessageBox.Show("you have enter wrong station name\npress OK to enter fresh value ", "ATTENTION!!", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

        if (rlt == MessageBoxResult.OK)
        {
            if (station.Contains(from.Text))
            {
                to.Text = "";
            }
            else if (station.Contains(to.Text))
            {
                from.Text = "";
            }
            else
            {
                from.Text = "";
                to.Text = "";
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Code on page 3:

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/PAGE2.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    string source = "";
    string destination = "";

    NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("source", out source);            
    NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("destination", out destination);
    start.Text = source;
    finish.Text = destination;
    cal(source, destination);
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the code?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You need to provide code and the exception for anyone to be able to help you with this.

Comment: Ok, I will show you the code. Do I have to show the code used for navigation or the whole code?

Comment: Only the navigation code and the exception you are getting.

Comment: i got two exception
1.)system.reflection.targetinvocationexception
2.)system.argumentexception